# DrawableWrapper missing from support v4 library

Tags: android, android-support-library

I tried replacing a local jar of the android-support-v13 library with a maven dependency like this

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
```

replaced with

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
```

However, when I try to compile this import fails

```
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper;
```

Has this class been removed from the support library?

Answer (score -1):

Try:`'compile com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.0'`

Version 21 of support library is quite old and so may not contain the needed class.

Comment: My targetSdkVersion is 21, an error is thrown if I try to compile a support library besides version 21.

Comment: Try adding compileSdkVersion=24

Comment: That would be too significant a change to make to production code.

Comment: compileSdkVersion is your way to tell Gradle what version of the Android SDK to compile your app with. Using the new Android SDK is a requirement to use any of the new APIs added in that level.

It should be emphasized that changing your compileSdkVersion does not change runtime behavior.

Therefore it is strongly recommended that you always compile with the latest SDK.   Source: https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd#.avtv35gtx

Comment: @Moses don't confuse targetSdk and compileSDK

Comment: I understand, my mistake. Is there any chance of issues arising from doing this?

Comment: "While new compiler warnings/errors may be present when changing your compileSdkVersion, your compileSdkVersion is not included in your APK: it is purely used at compile time" - so no